# One to one relation with Hibernate with shared key error when submitting JSP form

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create 2 tables with the first table having a primary key and the other table having it as its key. I'm using Spring mvc + hibernate, and it displayed this error when submitting the jsp form:

attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [model.TableB.resource]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [model.TableB.resource]

Table A:

```
@Entity
public class TableA{

    @Id
    private String sNum

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "resource",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TableB tableB;

    //other fields, getter setters
}
```

Table B:

```
@Entity
public class TableB{

    @Id
    private String id

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="resourceId")
    private TableA resource;

    //other fields, getter setters
}
```

These entities output the following into mysql:

```
TableA
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| sNum | column1tableA | column2tableA | ..other columns |
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| PK   |               |               |                 |
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+


TableB
+-------------------+---------+-----------------+
|    resourceId     | column1 | ..other columns |
+-------------------+---------+-----------------+
| PK FK from TableA |         |                 |
+-------------------+---------+-----------------+
```

Service:

```
public class tableAService {
    @Autowired
    TableARepository tableARepository; //this repository extends from jpa repository

    public void create(TableA tableA){
    tableARepository.save(tableA); 
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createTableA", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCreateTableAPage(Model model){
    if(!model.containsAttribute("tableA"))
        model.addAttribute("tableA", new TableA());

    return "createTableA";
} // this returns the registration page

@RequestMapping(value="/doCreateRe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doCreateRe(@Valid @ModelAttribute("tableA") TableA tableA, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()){

        return "redirect:/createPage";
    }try{
        myservice.create(tableA);
        return "viewPage";
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "error";
    }
} // this handles the onsubmit of the registration page
```

EDIT-2 (see sample output below): The string id for table A (manually inputted on the form by the user) should be saved as the foreign key on table B when submitting the form. For example, I wanted to save an object of type tableA, I will manually assign the id of it on the jsp form, fill other tableA-fields on the same page/form plus the related tableB object (that is, tableA.tableB.someField) also exists on the form (it will create a new row on table A and table B upon submitting the 'registration' form, table B's key would be the key from table A - see below)

createTableA page JSP:

```
<form:form  modelAttribute="tableA" method="POST" action="doCreateRe">
  ...
 <form:input path="sNum" required="true"/> <!-- sample input is abc123 -->
 <form:input path="column1tableA" required="true"/> <!-- sample input is chocolate -->
 <form:input path="column2tableA" required="true"/> <!-- sample input is beer -->
 <form:input path="tableB.column1" required="true"/> <!-- sample input is isDelicious -->
 <form:input path="tableB.column2" required="true"/> <!-- sample input is isBetter -->
 ...
</form:form>
```

Output that should appear on database upon form submission:

TableA:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
|    sNum    | column1tableA | column2tableA |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| abc123 PK  | chocolate     | beer          |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

TableB:

```
+------------+-------------+----------+
| resourceId |   column1   | column2  |
+------------+-------------+----------+
| abc123 FK  | isDelicious | isBetter |
+------------+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I finally found the fix. For [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973116/hibernate-onetoone-using-spring-and-jsp)

On TableA entity, I need to add an extra line for its setter.

```
@Entity
public class TableA{

    @Id
    private String sNum

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "resource",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TableB tableB;

    public TableB getTableB() {         
        return tableB;
    }

    public void setTableB(TableB tableB) {
        this.tableB = tableB;
        tableB.setResource(this); // added this line of code
    }

    //other fields, getter setters
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that TableB doesn't actually have TableA set against resource.

So somewhere in your create service code you should have something along the lines of:

```
tableB.setResource(tableA);
```

Review your create code and make the above change and it will work.

Also potential
The other issue could be that tableB object is not initialized within tableA thus when submited fails.

In your tableA class try this:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "resource",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private TableB tableB = new TableB();
```

or in the constructor:

```
this.tableB = new TableB();
```

And another option to try is to remove the:

```
@MapsId
```

in TableB from resource field. That is:

```
@MapsId
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="resourceId")
private TableA resource;
```

change it to

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="resourceId")
private TableA resource;
```

Comment: My service contains the save method from tableA repository. The form has a modelAttribute for tableA and it also needs to save the its related tableB field. How would I accomplish that? (see edit)

Comment: I tried creating a new instance of table2 before the service in the controller and setting it on asset but it still doesnt work, likewise with your solutions; I read that setting it optional=false fixes it for some but unfortunately same result

Comment: Found the 3rd possible reason and hopefully a fix. Check my re-edit.

Comment: Did you attempt the 3rd fix yet? I've tested it on my code and it works well.

Comment: Yes I get what you meant but I will need to assign a new id for tableB if I use your 3rd proposal, I edited my question for clarification

Comment: Have you tried specifying the primary key in MapsId such as MapsId("sNum") because your sNum is the primary key. Btw its tough to give you exact mappings unless the field names listed and such are not 100% as per your code.

Comment: Hm editing to MapsId("sNum") creates another column in TableB, the output to mysql tableB was: ID primary key column, resourceId foreign key column referenced as sNum, other columns. My first try was correct output on mysql which I wanted where the columns on tableB are: resourceId pk and fk from sNum tableA, other columns, but it results to the error when submitting the jsp, also re-edited again for clarity and added sample input on jsp